# Make 100% video height in Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have an [Owl Carousel able to mix video and images](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/video.html)...

Something like this: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwoJPB?editors=1010

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  video: true,
  videoWidth: 100,
  videoHeight: 100,
```

I would like, however, that the video height be adjusted to the height of all the carousel (100% of height, not a specific height), to be aligned with other carousel items.

I tried to let default values (false) to video height and width, and the result is the following: 
[image]

Is that possible to fully align simple and video items?

Comment: how many items you want  to display at a time?

Comment: should be parametrable... maybe 3, or 1...